# how to customize the gem: pace-rails default option startOnPageLoad in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I choose a `gem pace-rails` for show a progress bar,
but I just want to show it in limited requests,
I know it's need to change the default option `startOnPageLoad` to `false`.

*how can i do it in my `application.js` or anywhere?*  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I choose gem nprogress to show the progress bar.